# Using JSON callback in another function

Tags: jquery, json, callback, flickr

I'm trying to use a getJSON result obtained in a function in another function, but I don't know how to do it, anyone can help me?

I need to get text from an input and look in flickr for related images, later, I have to use that JSON call to take those pictures and show them in my page. This is what I have already done:

```
dataservices.pictureFeedService = function() {

    function searchForPictures(searchFilterEntry, callback) {
        var query = "http://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=" + searchFilterEntry + "&format=json&jsoncallback=?";

        $.getJSON(query,callback);
    }

    return {
        searchForPictures: searchForPictures
    };
}();
```

This is the second function, I want to use data obtained in previous JSON:

```
dataservices.picturesLayoutService = function() {

    function buildPicturesLayout(divImageContainer) {
        $.getJSON(function(data) {
            //read images url
            // Pop our HTML in the #images DIV
            $("#" + divImageContainer).html(htmlString);
        });
    }
    return {
        buildPicturesLayout: buildPicturesLayout
    };
}();
```

I call function this way:

```
dataservices.pictureFeedService.searchForPictures(searchTags, dataservices.picturesLayoutService.buildPicturesLayout("images"));
```

Comment: You're passing `dataservices.picturesLayoutService.buildPicturesLayout("images")` as your callback function. Is the "Images" string a placeholder to show us you're getting the results of the first getJson call?

Comment: Might check out jquery promise or the Q library. Makes dealing with these scenarios easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
dataservices.picturesLayoutService = function () {
    function buildPicturesLayout(divImageContainer, data) {
        $("#" + divImageContainer).empty();
        //iterate through the items and create a list
        $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
            $("#" + divImageContainer).append('<img src="' + item.media.m + '" />');
        })
    }
    return {
        buildPicturesLayout: buildPicturesLayout
    };
}();
//write a callback function which will receive the ajax response and pass it to the buildPicturesLayout method
dataservices.pictureFeedService.searchForPictures(searchTags, function (data) {
    dataservices.picturesLayoutService.buildPicturesLayout("images", data)
});
```